# convert winsound to a linux platform?

Tags: python, linux

On a chat script I was working on a while back, I used the winsound python library to play a 'ding' sound (ding.wav) when a new message was received. Now I am wondering how I can make this work for linux, only with a .ogg audio file. The code is below:

```
import sys
import util
import thread
import socket
import winsound

class ClientSocket():


rbufsize = -1
wbufsize = 0


def __init__(self, address, nickname=''):
    if type(address) == type(()) and type(address[0]) == type('') and type(address[1]) == type(1):
        pass
    else:
        print ('Address is of incorrect type. \n' +
              'Must be (serverHost (str), serverPort (int)).')
        sys.exit(1)

    if nickname:
        self.changeNick(nickname)
    else:
        self.changeNick(raw_input('Nickname: '))

    self.prompt_on = False
    self.address = address


def connect(self):
    self.connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.connection.connect(self.address)
    self.rfile = self.connection.makefile('rb', self.rbufsize)
    self.wfile = self.connection.makefile('wb', self.wbufsize)

    self.wfile.write('/nick ' + self.nickname + '\n')


def serve_forever(self):
    self.connect()

    thread.start_new_thread(self.acceptinput,())

    line = ""
    while line not in ('/exit','/quit', '/q'):
        self.prompt_on = True
        line = raw_input(self.prompt)
        self.prompt_on = False
        if line[:2] == '/n' or line[:5] == '/nick':
            self.changeNick(line.split(' ', 1)[1].strip())
        self.wfile.write(line + '\n')

    self.close()
    self.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.connection.close()


def changeNick(self, newNick):
    self.nickname = newNick
    self.prompt = self.nickname+': '
    self.backspace = '\b' * len(self.prompt)


def acceptinput(self):
    while 1:
        data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        if data:
            self.writedata(data)
            if 'Nickname successfully changed to' in data:
                self.changeNick(data.split('"')[1])


def writedata(self, data):
    if self.prompt_on:
        output = data if len(data) >= len(self.prompt) else data + ' ' * (len(self.prompt) - len(data))
        winsound.PlaySound("ding.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        sys.stdout.write(self.backspace + output + '\n' + self.prompt)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print data


def close(self):
    if not self.wfile.closed:
        self.wfile.flush()
    self.wfile.close()
    self.rfile.close()


def main():
serverHost = raw_input('Server IP/Hostname: ')
if not serverHost:
    serverHost = util.getIP()
else:
    serverHost = socket.gethostbyname(serverHost)

serverPort = input('Server Port: ')
address = (serverHost, serverPort)

client = ClientSocket(address)
print 'Connecting to server on %s:%s' % (serverHost, serverPort)
client.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

If someone could help me convert this to play a .ogg file instead, it would be awesome:)

Thanks, Sean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I ended up using the pygame library:

`import pygame`

`pygame.init()`

---

`pygame.mixer.music.load("ding.ogg")`

`pygame.mixer.music.play()`