# Python - winsound for Linux?

Tags: python, linux, beep

Is there some module for Linux equivalent to Windows `winsound`? I really need it for playing Morse Code. I tried `yum install beep`, but it doesn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: how about this: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Demo/scripts/morse.py

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: what are the nearest Linux and OSX equivalents of winsound.Beep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354586/python-what-are-the-nearest-linux-and-osx-equivalents-of-winsound-beep) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150267/convert-winsound-to-a-linux-platform

Comment: @yuvi, I get the following error: `audiodev.error: no audio device`

Comment: I don't know what to say, you should probably look into the alternatives @fedorqui linked.

Comment: Ok. I got it working using PyAudio: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202355/how-to-play-a-fixed-frequency-sound-using-python#answer-202390